# Correct way to avoid a ObjectDisposedException, in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, dispose

I am currently getting an ObjectDisposedException on the following line.

```
var client = ((Socket) asyncResult.AsyncState).EndAccept(asyncResult);
```

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.'

I was just wondering, what is the right way (in terms of best practice) to avoid an error like this? I'm unsure on how to handle it, how do I check if its disposed before hand, but is that what I should be doing? Or checking something else.

I'm self taught C# so I never learnt things like this, could someone give some insight?

Here is the full class:

```
internal sealed class SocketHandler : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private readonly Socket _serverSocket;

    public SocketHandler()
    {
        _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        Load();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _serverSocket?.Close(); // close also calls dispose...
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        var config = Program.Server.ConfigHandler;

        _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, config.GetConfigValueByKey("network.sockets.port").ToInt()));
        _serverSocket.Listen(int.Parse(config.GetConfigValueByKey("network.sockets.backlog")));
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(OnAcceptConnection, _serverSocket);
    }

    private void OnAcceptConnection(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_serverSocket == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var client = ((Socket) asyncResult.AsyncState).EndAccept(asyncResult);

            var playerHandler = Program.Server.BaseHandler.PlayerHandler;
            var players = playerHandler.Players;

            var config = Program.Server.ConfigHandler;

            var maxConnections = int.Parse(config.GetConfigValueByKey("game.players.limit"));
            var maxConnectionsPerIp = int.Parse(config.GetConfigValueByKey("game.players.ip_limit"));

            if (players.Count >= maxConnections)
            {
                Logger.Warn("Incoming connection was refused because the player limit was exceeded.");

                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();

                return;
            }

            if (players.Values.Count(x => x != null && !x._disconnected && x.getIp() == client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0]) > maxConnectionsPerIp)
            {
                Logger.Warn("Incoming connection was refused because the IP limit was exceeded.");

                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();

                return;
            }

            var clientId = Randomizer.Next(1, 10000);

            Program.Server.BaseHandler.PlayerHandler.TryAddPlayer(clientId, new Player(clientId, client, new InitialPacketParser()));
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Logger.Fatal(socketException, "Failed to accept socket connection.");
        }
        finally
        {
            _serverSocket?.BeginAccept(OnAcceptConnection, _serverSocket);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if object has been disposed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457521/how-to-check-if-object-has-been-disposed-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Since the socket is `private` I guess (though I'm not 100% sure) that your code is the only one disposing/closing this socket. So you could track that state yourself (probably need to do this in a thread-safe way).

Comment: Is there a chance that s.o. calls dispose on ur class from outside? U should also set _serversocket to null in dispose to make ur check in the Eventhandler work

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,c84007a498b38b5f) a `Socket` does not `Dispose` itself. So, since your `_serverSocket` is `private`, you are the only one to control *when* it is disposed.

Your `OnAcceptConnection()` method already started to try to check that, but not completely.

In your `Dispose()` method (or any other place where you `Close()` or `Dispose()` your `_serverSocket`) you need to also set `_serverSocket` to `null`. You can do it like this in a thread-safe way:

```
public class SocketHandler
{
    private Socket _serverSocket; // not read-only

    /* ... */

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Socket tmp = _serverSocket; // save instance
        _serverSocket = null; // set field to null
        tmp?.Close();
    }
```

Now your `OnAcceptConnection()` returns when it checks `if (_serverSocket == null)` and you avoid the exception.

Answer (score -1):

<del>The problem might also come from how you are using SocketHandler in the first place.</del> I can see nothing wrong with how the IDisposable pattern is implemented in your class. The normal way to avoid accessing a Disposable class after it has been disposed is wrapping it in a using statement which will auto-dispose the class after leaving the block:

```
using( SocketHandler handler = new SocketHandler())
{
    (...)
} //handler will be disposed and not accessible after here
```

For more information on this Microsoft Docs has a good [article explaining IDispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern)

**EDIT:**
Thanks for pointing out that I was on a completely wrong way to understand the question.

I at least recreated the scenario to best of my knowledge:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (C1 instance = new C1())
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(1000);

                bool disposed = (bool)typeof(C1).GetField("disposed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(instance);

                if (disposed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Already disposed will not call DoSomething()");
                }
                else
                {
                    instance.DoSomething();
                }

            });
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

class C1 : IDisposable
{
    bool disposed = false;
    public C1()
    {

    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("C1");

        Console.WriteLine("Still existing!");
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        Console.WriteLine("Disposed!");
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

And managed to workaround the exception with a reflection. Assuming that microsoft will have used the same pattern + namings as they are according to their Framework Design Guidelines this solution could at least be used as a **workaround**.

But I highly doubt that this the best way.

Comment: OP's problem is that `OnAcceptConnection` is called from another thread or asynchronously. This can still happen long after the socket or even their `SocketHandler` instance has been disposed. The question is about how to determine if `_serverSocket` (or the socket in `asyncResult.AsyncState`) already has been disposed when `OnAcceptConnection` is called. Your `using` statement doesn't help with that.