# BooleanDisposable usage guideline

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

As a general codding guideline when should one use `BooleanDisposable` from reactive extensions?

SOURCE:
https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Disposables/BooleanDisposable.cs

DOCUMENTATION:
https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Documentation/IntroToRx/B_Disposables.md

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Disposing an IDisposable [should be idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923853/should-idisposable-dispose-implementations-be-idempotent) - you should be able to Dispose it multiple times without negative consequences.

The ramifications of that are that you almost never care if an IDisposable has been disposed or not. You just Dispose it when you're done.

In my time of using Rx, I haven't come across a situation where I need to know if a Disposable instance has already been disposed. Typically the Disposable objects from Rx are composed and then returned from subscriptions. Knowing whether a Disposable has been disposed is rarely useful information.

If you need to do something *when* a Disposable is Disposed, then you can just use Disposable.Create and do whatever you need to do in the action.

So the only guideline I'd say around BooleanDisposable is that if you think you need it, your design might be more complex than it needs to be. Similar to guidelines for Finalizers, in that respect.

Comment: good point, I was thinking more about using it internally within a class so you don't execute sensitive code more then once.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not much feedback on question, I guess its a bit niche, here it goes:

If you put using `volatile bool _isDisposed` versus `BooleanDisposable` the former its a cleaner design.

More information on the volatile keyword: [Here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is for internal usage. It implements `volatile bool _isDisposed`. You could use it if you are manually creating your own `Observable` but [the latest documentation](https://introtorx.com/chapters/creating-observable-sequences) tells you not to do that. Which is normally good advice.

You may have noticed that when you subscribe to an observable you get an `IDisposable` back. So you need to return an `IDisposable` from your custom `Observable`.

All of their examples `return Disposable.Empty;` instead. This is where I would return the `BooleanDisposable` if I had a desire for something like the `.IsDisposed` property, which is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192206/how-does-one-tell-if-an-idisposable-object-reference-is-disposed). It's not there by default but you could add it if you wanted. This would be the reactive equivalent.